# Antd Form.List | Can I add label on top. only one line, not repeat

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have Form.list like below

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjh9m.png)

I want label on top, like this

[I wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AB2k.png)

is it possible?
I don't know which component to use..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Row` & `Col` from **antd** to layout your list labels.

[image]

```
import { PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, Form, Input, Row, Col, Typography } from 'antd';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className='container my-4'>
            <Form>
                <Form.List name='names'>
                    {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
                        <>
                            {!!fields.length && (
                                <Row align='middle'>
                                    <Col span={5} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                                        <Typography.Text>Subnet</Typography.Text>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col span={5} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                                        <Typography.Text>Netmask</Typography.Text>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col span={5} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                                        <Typography.Text>Router</Typography.Text>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col span={5} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }} />
                                    <Col span={4} />
                                </Row>
                            )}
                            {fields.map((field, index) => (
                                <Row key={index}>
                                    <Col span={5}>
                                        <Form.Item {...field} style={{ margin: '5px' }}>
                                            <Input placeholder='10.40.0.0' style={{ width: '100%' }} />
                                        </Form.Item>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col span={5}>
                                        <Form.Item {...field} style={{ margin: '5px' }}>
                                            <Input placeholder='255.255.255.0' style={{ width: '100%' }} />
                                        </Form.Item>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col span={5}>
                                        <Form.Item {...field} style={{ margin: '5px' }}>
                                            <Input placeholder='10.40.0.1' style={{ width: '100%' }} />
                                        </Form.Item>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col span={5}>
                                        <Form.Item {...field} style={{ margin: '5px' }}>
                                            <Input placeholder='IP Pool' style={{ width: '100%' }} />
                                        </Form.Item>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col span={4}>
                                        <Form.Item {...field} style={{ margin: '5px' }}>
                                            <Button onClick={() => remove(field.name)}>Delete</Button>
                                        </Form.Item>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            ))}

                            <Button type='dashed' onClick={() => add()} icon={<PlusOutlined />} style={{ margin: '5px' }}>
                                Add Subnet
                            </Button>
                        </>
                    )}
                </Form.List>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```